# Can not extract zip created by PHP and uploaded via cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to zip up a website and then upload to a CDN.  But I am getting an error message when the zip is opened by the cdn: `Error extracting zip: Zip end of central directory signature not found`

The website is not complex, just some root level html files and an image folder.  I created the zip file with PHP and when I open a downloaded copy on my computer it opens perfectly.  And when I manually upload it to the cdn it extracts perfectly.

But when I upload it via PHP/cURL I get the error.  So assume I am doing something wrong with my cURL functions.  My apologies if this is a simplistic mistake, it is my first foray into cURL.

My upload code:

```
<?php

$file = "/path/to/mytest.zip";
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer my_access_token";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/bla/bla/bla");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [$authorization, 'Content-Type: application/zip']);
$cfile = new CurlFile(@$file,  'application/zip');
$data = array('data-binary' => realpath($cfile));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this snippets on the RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

The correct implementation of CurlFile is:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$args['file'] = new CurlFile('filename.png', 'image/png');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```